# Bridgeless cubic graph has a 1-factor not containing two arbitrarily prescribed lines

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, connectedness, graph-connectivity

According to Petersen's theorem, every bridgeless cubic graph has a perfect matching.

While studying the proof of Petersen's theorem I came accross the following theorem
"every bridgeless cubic graph has a 1-factor not containing two arbitrarily prescribed lines", which I found in the PDF attached herewith (page 2, paragraph 3). Although they have mentioned the author who has proved it, the article is not in English but I would like to study the proof of this theorem as well.

Can someone help me in this regard? How to prove the theorem "every bridgeless cubic graph has a 1-factor not containing two arbitrarily prescribed lines"?

Thanks a lot in advance.

https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/127027/MathSlov_22-1972-4_8.pdf

Comment: Theorem 1 in the linked paper provides even more general claim (this is explicitly stated at the end of page 2) and has a proof shorter than one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the bridgeless cubic graph be $G=(V,E)$ and $G'=(V,E')$ be the graph where two arbitrary edges are removed.

By [Tutte's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem), if $G'$ has no perfect matchings, we have some set $U\subset V$ such that the odd components $O_i,\cdots,O_n$ of $G'-U$ satisfying $n > |U|$. Further, $n$ and $|U|$ must be of the same parity since $|V|$ is even. Therefore $n\geq |U|+2$.

Denote the edges (in $G$) connecting $V$ to $O_i$ be $s_i$ and the edges connecting $O_i$ to the other odd components be $t_i$.

Since only 2 edges are removed, and $t_i$'s can only arise from these edges, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n t_i \leq 4$.

Next, since the graph is 3-regular, the sum over all $s_i$'s must not be greater than $3|U|$ and we have $\sum_{i=1}^n s_i \leq 3|U|$.

Now, note that the graph is bridgeless. Hence there must be more than one edge connecting each component $V_i$ to other components. The handshaking lemma necessitates the edges inside the component $V_i$ to be even (since it is also a graph) and the sum of all degrees of $V_i$ in $G$ is odd. Therefore, the edges not within the component will be at least 3. (i.e. $s_i+t_i\geq 3$)

Combining all 3 inequalities, we get $3n=3\sum_{i=1}^n s_i+t_i\leq 4+3|U|$. Rearranging, we get $3(|U|+2-n)-2\geq 0$.

This is a contradiction to Tutte's theorem since $n\geq |U|+2$. Therefore, $G'$ must have a perfect matching.

Comment: Thank you very much @David